# Ошибка System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

Задание таково
Из массива чисел В(12) получить массив А следующим образом: каждое число, начиная со второго,
заменить суммой или произведением предыдущего и последующего(большим значением).
Первое число переписать в массив А, если оно не отрицательное, иначе заменить его в В числом 5.2
В коде ошибка выдается в этой строке

> double S = B[i - 1] + B[i + 1];
> Мой код(я только учусь программировать)

````
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите значениz элементов массива");
            double x = 0;
            int u = 0;
            double[] B=new double[12];
            double[] A = new double[12];
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                B[i] = 0;
            }
            for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
            {
                x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                B[i] = x;
            }
            
            for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
            {
                double S = B[i - 1] + B[i + 1];
                double P = B[i - 1] * B[i + 1];
                if (S > P && (S != 0 | P != 0))
                {
                    A[i] = S;
                }
                else if (P > S && (S != 0 | P != 0))
                {
                    A[i] = P;
                }
                else B[i] = 5.2;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(A[i]+"");
            }
        }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмём абстрактный пример:

В массиве например 10 элементов. Нумерация начинается с 0. У последнего элемента индекс 9. Теперь спросите у себя, что произойдёт, если на последней итерации цикла, когда `i = 9`  вы будете обращаться по индексу `i + 1` ?

Вам надо этот момент учесть.

Comment: Помогло,спасибо,теперь лучше понимаю устройство массивов